# Does bash have a boolean and/or operator that doesn't short circuit?

Tags: bash

I'm looking to be able to always execute both validateA and validateB:

```
function validateA() {
  echo "A [ok]"
  return 0
}

function validateB() {
  echo "B [ok]"
  return 0
}

if ! validateA | ! validateB; then 
  echo "validation [fail]"
  exit 1
else
  echo "validation [ok]"
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call them regardless and capture the return values:

```
function validateA() {
    echo "A [fail]"
    return 1
}

function validateB() {
    echo "B [ok]"
    return 0
}

validateA ; vA=$?
validateB ; vB=$?

if [[ $vA -ne 0 || $vB -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo "validation [fail]"
    exit 1
else
    echo "validation [ok]"
    exit 0
fi
```

This outputs:

```
A [fail]
B [ok]
validation [fail]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and ended up doing something like this:

```
rc=0
if ! validateA ; then rc=1; fi
if ! validateB ; then rc=1; fi
return $rc
```

It's the same principle as other answers but a more condensed syntax.

Answer (score 1):

First idea which comes to my mind is just call each function consistently, save return values and analyze it later. Like this:

```
validateA
a_retval=$?

validateB
b_retval=$?

if [ $a_retval -ne 0 -o $b_retval -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "validation [fail]"
  exit 1
else
  echo "validation [ok]"
  exit 0
fi
```